# Incompatible pointer types assigning to NSMutableString from NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I an new to iOS.

I have the following warning which I don t know how to solve:

```
NSString *getNos=[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

NSMutableArray *allNos = [[getNos stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

NSString *matchNo = [[allNos lastObject] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

At the second and the third line I have the following warning message:

```
Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray * from NSArray *
and
Incompatible pointer types sending NSString * to parameter of type NSMutableString*
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:` returns a `NSArray` not a `NSMutableArray`.

Either change `NSMutableArray` to `NSArray` or add `mutableCopy` if you really need a `NSMutableArray`:

```
NSMutableArray *allNos = [[[getNos stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];
```

Also there is a typo: a missing "*".

Note: By using intermediates the code is easier to see and easier to pinpoint errors:

```
NSString *getNos = @"a b, c d";
NSString *cleanNos = [getNos stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSMutableArray *allNos = [[cleanNos componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"allNos: %@", allNos);
```

NSLog output:

```
allNos: (
    ab,
    cd
)
```

Comment: and for the second warning that i have at line with NSString matchNo what should I do?

Comment: Can't really tell, it might be a false positive due to the `MutableArray` error. See my note in the answer, that complies and runs fine. Also, in Objective-C the general case is not to use the Mutable versions unless there is a specific need.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign NSArray to NSMutableArray but you also missing the pointer *, replace this

```
 NSMutableArray  allNos = ...
```

with this

```
NSMutableArray  *allNos = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray://YOUR stuff here]
```